Cannot make purchases on any Gmail, Google keeps flagging it as fraud even though it's my credit card
How can I start making in-app purchases again in Coin Master on my Google Play Store when it keeps flagging every Gmail account I make as a fraud?
No matter which one I use, it won't let me make the purchases, it stops me. I tried everything.

If the problem is your credit card then don't use it. Google offers vouchers you can buy and add to your account. You can even buy them online using your credit card, e.g. at Amazon.

Thank you kindly
